# How can I put an extra value?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a table (`DataGridView`) like this :

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3

3    | Mars | Regular
```

Here is my code:

```
For a As Integer = 0 To Form3.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    For b As Integer = 0 To Form3.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
        For c As Integer = 0 To Form3.DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
            If Form3.DataGridView1.Rows(c).Cells(2).Value = "Regular" Then
                If Form3.DataGridView1.Rows(b).Cells(1).Value = Form3.MetroComboBox7.Items(0) Then
                    fair = 7 * Form3.DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(0).Value
                    Label1.Text += fair
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next
```

I want to set that if **Regular** is selected on `Col3` and **Mars** on `Col2` then the value is **7** and it will multiply by row `Col1` and it will be the same every row.

Comment: Why are you looping through your `DataGridView` rows three times? Shouldn't you remove the loops `For b` and `For c` and reference to `a` like such `.Rows(a)`?

Comment: im trying to loop every value in 3 columns

Comment: You don't need to. Just use the `For a As Integer` loop and reference to `a` on all your `.Rows(a)`. Get rid of the `For b` and `For c` loops.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the event `dtgv.CellMouseClick`.

Then you create conditions that you want. I give you an example here :

```
Public Sub event_select() Handles dtgv.CellMouseClick
        Dim row As Integer = dtgv.CurrentRow.Index()
        ' If the column 2 and 3 are selected
        If dtgv.Rows(row).Cells(1).Selected = True And dtgv.Rows(row).Cells(2).Selected = True Then
            ' If the value of the 2nd column is Mars and the value of the 3rd column is Regular
            If dtgv.Rows(row).Cells(1).Value = "Mars" And dtgv.Rows(row).Cells(2).Value = "Regular" Then
                Label1.Text = 7 * dtgv.Rows(row).Cells(0).Value
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

You should also check that no other rows have cells selected.

Comment: how can do this without event ? just on load

Comment: When you load your form, you don't have selected cells, right ?

Comment: You could also fire events of your form 3 to other forms

Answer (score 0):

One loop for all rows is enough to calculate "fair" for all rows

```
Const REGULAR_VALUE As String = "Regular"
Const FAIR_COEFFICENT As Integer = 7
Dim fairSum As Integer = 0

For Each row As DataGridViewRow in DataGridView1.Rows
    If REGULAR_VALUE.Equals(row.Cells(2).Value.ToString()) = False Then Continue For
    If Equals(MetroComboBox7.Items(0), row.Cells(1).Value) = False Then Continue For

    Dim col1Value As Integer = Integer.Parse(row.Cells(1).Value)
    Dim fair As Integer = col1Value  * FAIR_COEFFICENT 
    fairSum += fair
Next

Label1.Text = fairSum.ToString()
```

And set `Option Strict On` in your project or at least in the code file(first line of file).
This will save you time by giving fast feedback about possible type converting errors during compile time.

Create class which represent your data in strongly typed manner

```
Public Class Ticket
    Public Property Passenger As Integer
    Public Property Destination As String
    Public Property Status As String     
End Class
```

Then you can add rows to the DataGridView in easy way in your form

```
Public Class YourForm
    Private _tickets As New BindigList(Of Ticket)()

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent() ' Forms required method

        DataGridView1.DataSource = _tickets 
    End Sub 

    Private Sub Populate(passenger As Integer, destination As String, Status As String)
        Dim newTicket As New Ticket With
        {
            .Passenger = passenger,
            .Destination = destination,
            .Status = Status,
        }
        _ticket.Add(newTicket)
    End Sub  

    'Then you can loop all rows with correct types
    Private Sub Calculate()
        Dim fairSum As Integer = 0

        For Each ticket As Ticket in _tickets
            If REGULAR_VALUE.Equals(ticket.Status) = False Then Continue For
            If ticket.Destination.Equals(MetroComboBox7.Items(0)) = False Then Continue For

            Dim fair As Integer = ticket.Passenger * FAIR_COEFFICENT 
            fairSum += fair
        Next

        Label1.Text = fairSum.ToString()
    End Sub     
End Class
```

Comment: it says "Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: You should give him the line where the error occurs @NeCat

Comment: Dim col1Value As Integer = DirectCast(row.Cells(0).Value, Integer) 
this line says "Specified cast is not Valid"

Comment: @NeCat what is the type of value in first column?

Comment: Private Sub populate(passenger As String, destination As String, Status As String)
        Dim row As String() = New String() {passenger, destination, Status}

        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(row)
This is the method that i used for every column,
combobox for col 1 has integer value

Comment: So first column's value is `string` which is very odd because you going to calculate it later. Check updated answer

Comment: @Fabio same column problem says "Input string formatted" 
ill try to change it to integer and try this code and the previous one

Comment: @Fabio still the same problem

Comment: @Fabio do you have facebook ? so  that i can send the whole code so you can see the problem ?

Comment: @NeCat Earn more reputation then you will be able to create chat rooms.

Comment: @Fabio i need bindingsource ?

Comment: I don't think so, `BindingList` will be enough

Comment: i created a new form 
 the problem says it not defined  in this row
 Private _tickets As New BindigList(Of Ticket)
this 2 also not declared says 
_ticket.Add(newTicket)
i already created the Class where

Comment: i created a new form the problem says it not defined in this row Private _tickets As New BindigList(Of Ticket) this 2 also not declared says _ticket.Add(newTicket) i already created the Class